# from python crash course web app django project

Tags: python, django, crash

[enter image description here][1]

I am trying to do the web app project and attempting to print topic ids but it prints only Object(number) and I am pretty sure it has to do something with django admin
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WkEr.png

Comment: Please elaborate the problem you are facing with some code excerpts and desired output.

Comment: by clicking on the image link you can see that on the left side ,,the desired output is given as ==>  [<Topic: Chess>, <Topic: Rock Climbing>] and i am getting this ==> [<Topic: Topic object (3)>, <Topic: Topic object (4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your `__str__` function so that it belongs to the class. So it has to get 4 spaces or 1 tab.

Comment: did that however still the same output